# Dereferencing pointer to a pointer doesn't work when I pass it to a function. Why? (C)

Tags: c

I tried everything I could think off. I don't know if I'm missing something obvious. Why does this work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void test_matrix(int** matrix)
{
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(matrix+j+4*i));
        }
    }
    /**
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(*(matrix+i)+j));
        }
    }
    */
}
int main()
{
    int matrix[4][4];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
    test_matrix(matrix);
}
```

But the commented section doesn't work. I also tried matrix[i][j] and it still won't work. My program times out.
EDIT: I added the function calling in MAIN.

Comment: If the first version works, the argument you’re passing with the call to `test_matrix` is wrong. `%d` doesn’t expect an `int*`, which is what `*(matrix+j+4*i)` is when `matrix` is an `int**`.

Comment: You need to do it twice -- if this is an array and you want to use it like an array than use the `[`]` or cast it to the new type after the pointer arithmatic.

Comment: Better to show how `test_matrix` is being called, that is how `matrix` was constructed before passing to the function

Comment: `matrix[i][j]` can work, depending on how `matrix` was declared and initialized in the caller. But you haven't shown the code that calls your function. See [mcve].

Comment: Start by fixing [the errors the compiler is giving](https://pastebin.com/9FuTUPEi).

Comment: You'd better revise pointers chapter of a C book. How you conceptualize a pointer in your head is way different from how the compiler treat them. As far as I understand; you conceptualize a double dimension matrix had to be passed via a double star pointer. Things doesn't work that way in C. For a matrix `int matrix[4][4]`, matrix data is laid down in the memory as 16 (= 4 × 4) consecutive integers, starting from the address `matrix` or `&matrix[0]` or `&matrix[0][0]`. Not only the receiving function but the `main` function as well doesn't even know that your matrix has 4 rows & 4 columns.

Comment: The array `matrix` to the compiler is simply 16 integers laid consecutive in the memory. So, your calling line is better be like `test_matrix(matrix, 4, 4)` and your function decoration is better be like `void test_matrix(int *matrix, int no_of_rows, int no_of_cols)`.

Comment: How does the compiler not yell at you for passing an `int(*)[4]` to an `int**` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

The error is that this 2D-array is laid out as 4 x 4 = 16 integers. But your function expects a pointer to pointers.

It's right that at the calling site the address of `matrix` is provided as the argument. But unlike some commenter said, it's not a pointer to `int` but a pointer to an `int`-array.

To handle this address of the 2D-array correctly you need to tell it your function, like this:

```
void test_matrix(int (*matrix)[4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", *(*(matrix + i) + j));
        }
    }
}
```

or like this:

```
void test_matrix(int matrix[][4])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Which kind of access you use doesn't matter, sometimes it's just a matter of taste. These expressions are equivalent, actually `p[i]` is syntactic sugar for `*(p + i)`:

```
*(*(matrix + i) + j)

matrix[i][j]
```

---

*Note 1: As some commenters already recommend, you should raise the warning level to the maximum and correct the source until all diagnostics are handled.*

*Note 2: When your arrays vary in their dimensional sizes you need to think of a way to tell these sizes to your function.*